# I want to load large dataset which is in csv format to neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a 162MB file in csv format, from which I have to load 10M of rows in `neo4j` and make relations between two columns. I have increased java heap memory to: `dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=6000m` `dbms.memory.heap.max_size=4096m` also I increased the page cache size to: `dbms.memory.pagecache.size=2g` My system has 6GB RAM installed. In the cypher query I used merge because I don't want duplicates.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS row 
Merge (a:citedd {citeddlabel: row.citing}) 
Merge (b:citng {citnglabel: row.cited}) CREATE (a)-[:r]->(b);
```

---

All the data should be loaded so that I can view its graph.

Comment: Reformat code and unbold text

Comment: Please state a question.

Comment: Please include what're the issues?